# Defining a new command using another new command

Tags: nesting, csname

I want to defined a command that uses another command in its definition, like so:

```
\newcommand{\command1}{$\alpha^x$}
\newcommand{\command2}{\command1_\beta}
```

I understand that `csname` may be used for that (and also to use numbers in the name ov the command, I believe) - but using `csname` seems not so easy and unfortunately I don't have the time to familiarize myself with these finer point of TeX and other examples . Could you please help me?

Please not that this command should only be used inside a math environment like so:

```
\begin{document}
Here is a hitherto unknown mathematical object: $\command2+1$. %should display $\alpha^x_{\beta} +1$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\newcommand*\commandA{\alpha^{x}}
\newcommand*\commandB{\commandA_{\beta}}
```

And then use `$\commandB+1$`.

Using numbers in commands is not possible except doing hacks, but it's not a good solution. If you want to define csnames followed by numbers there are already hacks written. Here's a simpler trick, but I don't recommend it.

```
\newcount\tmpcount
\newcommand*\command{\afterassignment\docommand\tmpcount=}
\newcommand*\docommand{\csname command\the\tmpcount\endcsname}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname command1\endcsname{\alpha^{x}}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname command2\endcsname{\command1_{\beta}}
```

but it's a bit of a mess, couldn't you use `\command{1}` rather than `\command1`? Or just go with `\commandA` and `\commandB`.

Comment: great answer! Could you please let me know , why your trick isn't recommended, is it brittle and may not work anymore for later versions of LaTeX?

Comment: Well, numbers were not designed to go into the name of commands, so this is just that, a trick in some sense. Much better if you went with `\commandA` or `\command{10}` which would be “standard”. In this case you can go with `\command12` but still it feels like an unnecessary hack.

Answer (score 6):

Another simple way. Here, the numbers are not part of the command's name, but the parameter of `\command`. It's a bit of a scam.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\command}[1]{\ifx1#1\alpha^{x}\fi\ifx2#1\command{1}_{\beta}\fi}
\begin{document}
\[\command1+1+\command2+2\] % More correctly: \[\command{1}+1+\command{2}+2\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for numbers bigger than 10 (e.g., `\command10` wouldn't work) but it's the easiest approach, if OP is willing to use `\command{10}`. By the way, you could use `\ifcase#1\or \alpha^x\or\command{1}_{\beta}\or ...\fi`.

Comment: hehe, very clever way, if I were to go with smallnumber, +1

Comment: @Manuel -- Yes, yes, you are right!!! I was concentrating on cases 1 and 2 only:) The best way the `\ifcase`!!!